Niederlassungserlaubnis (Germany) and Institutional fees in Netherlands
My daughter has Niederlassungserlaubnis from Germany and wants to study in Netherlands, i.e. we do not have a passport yet.

Do we still have to pay the institutional fees as we hold Indian passport still?
If we get a German passport before the start of second year of study in Netherlands, can we get rid of institutional fees from second year?

